# Promises with typescript-2.x gives error :Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

After upgrading angular to 4.x from 2.x and typescript to 2.x started giving following error which was working fine with previous version

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type
>   '((onfulfilled?: (value:
>   MediaStream) => TResult1 | Prom...' has no compatible call signatures.

My code is as following

```
getMediaStream(options:{video: boolean, audio: boolean}) {
    let self: Caller = this;
    return self.getUserMedia(options)
      .then(stream => {
        console.log('got our media stream:', stream);
        self.privateMedia = createObjectURL(stream);
        self.privateStream = stream;
        return stream;
      })
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('Could not get access to microphone & camera');
      });
  }

  public getUserMedia(constraints) {
    if (window.navigator.mediaDevices && window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
      return window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const getMedia = window.navigator.getUserMedia;
      if (!getMedia) reject(new Error('Browser unsupported'));
      getMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typecasting `self.getUserMedia(options)` to `any`/`Promise` resolved the problem.

So I used following code and it worked:

```
getMediaStream(options:{video: boolean, audio: boolean}) {
    let self = this;
    return (<Promise>self.getUserMedia(options))// in place of promise 'any' or other any superclass to promise will work as well 
      .then(stream => {
        console.log('got our media stream:', stream);
        self.privateMedia = createObjectURL(stream);
        self.privateStream = stream;
        return stream;
      }).catch(() => {
        console.log('Could not get access to microphone & camera');
      });
  }
```